How can we access rabbitmq dashboard in adobe commerce cloud?
I need to see my queues and other details in rabbitmq dashboard. In local, we can install rabbitmq and use it's dashboard but for cloud,unable to figure out how we can see the dashboard.

You can access RabbitMQ in the cloud using the steps outlined in this article.
https://experienceleague.adobe.com/en/docs/commerce-cloud-service/user-guide/configure/service/rabbitmq

Thanks @GrazittiDev.
